# segmentation fault when trying to dereference a dynamically allocated pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have a dynamically allocated `char` array, I want to combine two strings into it, so I tried the following:

```
char *strcpy2 (char *str1, char *str2)
{
    int total = strlen (str1) + strlen (str2) + 1;
    char *nstr = malloc (sizeof (char) * total);
    while (*str1 != '\0') *nstr++ = *str1++;
    while (*str2 != '\0') *nstr++ = *str2++;
    *nstr = '\0';
    printf ("size: %d\n", strlen (nstr));
    return &(nstr[0]);
}

int main (void)
{
    char *concat = strcpy2 ("Hello, ", "World.");
    puts (concat);
    free (concat);
    return 0;
}
```

When I ran it, it printed the size of `nstr` is 0 and then `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

However when I did this:

```
char *strcpy2 (char *str1, char *str2)
{
    int total = strlen (str1) + strlen (str2) + 1;
    char *nstr = malloc (sizeof (char) * total);
    char *p = nstr;
    while (*str1 != '\0') *p++ = *str1++;
    while (*str2 != '\0') *p++ = *str2++;
    *p = 0;
    printf ("size: %d\n", strlen (nstr));
    return nstr;
}
```

It worked fine and printed the correct length of `nstr`. I'm puzzled, what caused the crash?

Comment: You should use gdb to debug file.core and see exactly where is the problem.

Comment: `x[0]` means the same as `*x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the value of `nstr` that was originally returned by `malloc()`.

Your first code block increments `nstr` until it points to the end of the allocated memory. The code then attempts to use and free that address, which is not owned by your program.

You need to save the starting address of the string so you can return it.

Comment: Nope, `&*` is completely useless, it cancels itself out.

Comment: @razzak: `&(nstr[0])` returns the same as `nstr`. At this point, `nstr[0]` references the last character in the string because the value  of `nstr` was changed.

Comment: @JonathanWood thanks for clarifying that, i was confused because i saw instances where it's been used to get the pointer of an array like `char arr[20] = "whatever"; char *ptr = &(char[0])`, so i thought it would always return a pointer to the begining of the array.

Answer (score 1):

In your first case, you increment the `nstr` constantly, and in the end, you use

```
printf ("size: %d\n", strlen (nstr));
```

where `nstr` points to the final location after all the increment (containing `null`).Results in 0 length.  Then, you return the incremented pointer to the caller and try to `free()` it. Results in [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

OTOH, in the second case, you have the pointer to the primarily allocated memory intact, through which you count the string length, returns correct value and later, `free()`-ing is also proper, so that works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In the first function, you're returning the wrong pointer. It's pointing at the null terminator of the string, so the length is zero. When you try to `free()` it, it isn't a pointer you got from `malloc()`. Undefined behavior results.

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing the `nstr` pointer when copying the two strings, and that's the pointer you're using to represent the string itself. Simply copy it in another variable and use it when referring to the string:

```
char *strcpy2 (char *str1, char *str2)
{
    int total = strlen (str1) + strlen (str2) + 1;
    char *nstr = malloc (sizeof (char) * total);
    char *str = nstr;                                // the string
    while (*str1 != '\0') *nstr++ = *str1++;
    while (*str2 != '\0') *nstr++ = *str2++;
    *nstr = '\0';
    printf ("size: %d\n", strlen (str));             // used here
    return str;                                      // and here
}
```

You can see it in action here: https://ideone.com/ncpVMU

I also took the liberty of fixing your goofy return statement:

```
return &(nstr[0]);
```